# Jinja variables in function

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I have defined a variable in jinja by using:

`{% set my_var = 10 %}`

And a macro by doing:

```
{% macro my_function(my_var) %}
    where my_col > my_var
{% endmacro %}
```

I want to call the macro on the variable I've set in order to obtain the string:

```
where my_col > 10
```

I've tried with

```
{{my_function(my_var)}}
```

but it doesn't work. I'm not sure if I have to change the call or the macro. Do you know how can  I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug in the function definition, it needs to be defined like:

```
{% macro my_function(my_var) %}
    where my_col > {{ my_var }}
{% endmacro %}
```